# How to refresh cassandra contact-points without application restart? Cassandra Driver 4.4. URL refresh support

Tags: spring-data-cassandra

I have seen this feature that reloads the config from a URL:
https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/4.0/com/datastax/oss/driver/api/core/config/DriverConfigLoader.html#fromUrl-java.net.URL-

Do we have anything to refresh the properties inside the jar without restarting the jvm in spring-data-cassandra?

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-cassandra/2.2.4.RELEASE Spring Data Cassandra does not support 4.4 datastax driver version

Thanks,

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `basic.config-reload-interval` in the driver configuration, or check [our documentation on configuration](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.4/manual/core/configuration/): the driver will automatically reload its configuration, by default every 5 minutes.

However contact points are generally only useful at session initialization: once the session is initialized, the driver maintains a set of available nodes that reflects the actual state of the cluster. You shouldn't need to refresh contact points, unless your application creates many `CqlSession` objects (which is an anti-pattern).

Comment: Spring Data Cassandra does not support driver 4.4 https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-cassandra/2.2.4.RELEASE

Comment: Yes it does, in 3.0.0.M1 released this year. Sorry I thought you were referring to this milestone since you mention "Driver 4.4" in the title of your question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! 
Is it stable for production use? I should just call that property in the application.properties or application.yml?

Comment: Hi @adutra, my Cassandra cluster is deployed on K8S environment. If all my pods go down (for example complete outage) and comes up with different IP, then I may require to update contact points. Is restarting the application only available mean to me?

Comment: Hi @ManishKhandelwal, unfortunately yes, if all the pods go down and are brought up with entirely different IPs, then you need to close your session and create another one, because contact points are not hot-reloadable.